# Can anyone explain me what is wrong with my dynamic programming approach to project euler 15?

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I am learning dynamic programming and have attempted solve [Problem 15 of Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=15) using dynamic programming. 
Although I do know that the problem is solvable using binomial co-efficient, I wanted to see how much have I learned dynamic programming and thus tried. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int gridsize;
    cin>>gridsize;


    int** grid = new int*[gridsize+1];
    for ( int i = 0; i < gridsize+1; i++) {
        grid[i] = new int[gridsize+1];
    }

    //Initialize the grid distances

    for ( int i = 1; i <= gridsize ; i++) {
        grid[i][0] = 1;
        grid[0][i] = 1;
    }
    grid[0][0] = 0;

    for ( int i = 1; i <= gridsize ; i++) {
        for ( int j = 1; j <= gridsize ; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = grid[i-1][j] + grid[i][j-1];
        }
    }
    cout<<grid[gridsize][gridsize]<<endl;
    delete(grid);   
    return 0;
}
```

The expected answer is 137846528820, while the answer that I am getting is 407575348.

Comment: What is the expected result, and what do you actually get? Could you please edit the question to add that?

Comment: Sure, let me make the change as suggested.

Comment: I see a possible issue with 1 based indexing into 2 dimensional array as opposed to a correct 0 based indexing.

Comment: The most fundamental error (i.e. the one easiest to correct) is of course that it uses memory-owning pointers, and consequently leaks memory.

Comment: Following Konrad's comment: `std::vector<T>` is good, have some.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is fairly correct, the problem is that you are getting a case of integer overflow. Here is a modified version of your code that works perfectly. Simply change the `int` to an `long long unsigned` type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned long long ull;
int main()
{
    ull gridsize;
    cin>>gridsize;


    ull** grid = (ull**) malloc((gridsize+1)*sizeof(ull*));
    for ( int i = 0; i < gridsize+1; i++) {
        grid[i] = (ull*) malloc((gridsize +1)*sizeof(ull));
    }

    //Initialize the grid distances

    for ( int i = 1; i <= gridsize ; i++) {
        grid[i][0] = 1;
        grid[0][i] = 1;
    }
    grid[0][0] = 0;

    for ( int i = 1; i <= gridsize ; i++) {
        for ( int j = 1; j <= gridsize ; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = grid[i-1][j] + grid[i][j-1];
        }
    }
    cout<<grid[gridsize][gridsize];
    free(grid);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why'd you change the `new` to `malloc`?

Comment: Oh sorry, being a C programmer it was completely out of habit. `malloc` is just as good.

Comment: “just as good” … not in C++. Then again, neither is apppropriate here (in C++).

Answer (score 2):

It seems you overflowed the `int` datatype. According to [calculation](http://www.google.gr/search?q=137846528820%20modulo%202%5E32):

> 137 846 528 820 modulo (2^32) = 407 575 348

Answer (score -2):

It seems a handy debugging (or original development) tool here is a spreadsheet: you can quickly build one to solve the problem following your algorithm, which will show you the result at each step. This should allow you to easily identify the overflow in the lower right side of the grid (starting with grid[16][18]).

Comment: I thought I identified the issue, pointed at its exact location and, additionally, suggested an easy-to-use tool to detect this and similar problems. If you think I could have done better, please recommend an improvement - otherwise your comment is not helpful.